# how to estimate parameters of a triangular distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a set of observations, and they come from a triangular distribution. Now I want to estimate its parameters, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach. For the triangle distribution you have three parameters $(a,b,c)$ where 
$$
P(X<a) = 0\\
P(X>b) = 0
$$
so you could use the $\min\lbrace X_i \rbrace$ and $\max\lbrace X_i \rbrace$ as pretty decent estimates.

So the peak is the main thing to estimate, and that can be done with with the likeihood method. Do you know much about this approach?

$\textbf{This approach gets better with the more sampling you do}$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean I divide [min, max] into N intervals, and calculate the frequency of each interval, and choose the peak?

Comment: That's a very empirical approach, and it may be sufficient depending on the samples. But I was talking about picking a $c$ that maximizes the LH function.

Comment: It is difficult to formulate the LH function, given an observation x, the value of f(x) is based on c

Comment: Hold your horses on accepting this answer. Are you sure I helped you sufficiently? i.e. have you constructed the MLE for your problem?

Comment: nope!, I use min to estimate the lower bound, and max to estimate the upper bound. Based on the sample, I can get the mean, so the mode can be calculated by 3*mean - (upper + lower)

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate the bounds by the $\min$ and the $\max$ of the sample. For the mode, several methods can be used. For example:

- the methods of moments (having previously estimated the two other parameters)
- estimate the density (with a kernel method) and then take the mode of the estimated density.
- chose a maximum likelihood estimator, as Chinny84 said.